# how to connect android app ran in android device in php using json?

Tags: android

When I run my android app on an emulator, everything is fine. But whenever i run it on my android device, there are errors. The errors are JSON Parser and Buffer Error and there's an orange(color) error saying, "There's a problem in the url".

Here's an example of my url:

```
private static final String url_login="http://192.168.43.2/android_connect/login2.php";
```

192.168.43.2 is the ip add of my laptop.

```
11-03 19:57:39.646: I/System.out(10771): [socket][1:49188] exception
11-03 19:57:39.646: I/System.out(10771): [CDS]close[49188]
11-03 19:57:39.647: I/System.out(10771): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:49188]
11-03 19:57:39.647: W/System.err(10771): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /192.168.43.2:80 timed out
11-03 19:57:39.648: W/System.err(10771):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
11-03 19:57:39.648: W/System.err(10771):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
11-03 19:57:39.648: W/System.err(10771):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
11-03 19:57:39.648: W/System.err(10771):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
11-03 19:57:39.648: W/System.err(10771):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:365)
11-03 19:57:39.648: W/System.err(10771):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:587)
11-03 19:57:39.648: W/System.err(10771):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:511)
11-03 19:57:39.648: W/System.err(10771):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:489)
11-03 19:57:39.648: W/System.err(10771):    at com.example.libsystemfinal.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:65)
11-03 19:57:39.649: W/System.err(10771):    at com.example.libsystemfinal.MainActivity$LogIn.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:81)
11-03 19:57:39.649: W/System.err(10771):    at com.example.libsystemfinal.MainActivity$LogIn.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-03 19:57:39.649: W/System.err(10771):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-03 19:57:39.650: W/System.err(10771):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-03 19:57:39.650: W/System.err(10771):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-03 19:57:39.650: W/System.err(10771):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-03 19:57:39.650: W/System.err(10771):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-03 19:57:39.651: E/Buffer Error(10771): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
11-03 19:57:39.651: E/JSON Parser(10771): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
11-03 19:57:39.652: W/System.err(10771): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-03 19:57:39.653: W/System.err(10771):    at com.example.libsystemfinal.MainActivity$LogIn.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:83)
11-03 19:57:39.661: W/System.err(10771):    at com.example.libsystemfinal.MainActivity$LogIn.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-03 19:57:39.661: W/System.err(10771):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-03 19:57:39.661: W/System.err(10771):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-03 19:57:39.661: W/System.err(10771):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-03 19:57:39.661: W/System.err(10771):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-03 19:57:39.661: W/System.err(10771):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-03 19:57:39.663: D/GraphicBuffer(10771): close handle(0x60e1d7f8) (w:528 h:144 f:1)
11-03 19:57:39.663: D/GraphicBuffer(10771): close handle(0x60cfaf38) (w:528 h:144 f:1)
11-03 19:57:39.664: D/GraphicBuffer(10771): close handle(0x6075c9d8) (w:528 h:144 f:1)
11-03 19:57:39.670: D/dalvikvm(10771): threadid=12: interp stack at 0x60e23000
11-03 19:57:39.675: V/InputMethodManager(10771): onWindowFocus: android.widget.EditText{42568ad0 VFED..CL .F....ID 60,115-480,170 #7f05003d app:id/password} softInputMode=32 first=false flags=#40010100
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the full logcat print please?

Comment: @Nanoc I have added the logcat.

Comment: That shows a timeout, your server is not reachable by the device, doesnt look like a programming error.

Comment: but everytime i run it, that's the error appearing. dont have idea how to fix it

Comment: Sure, if its not reachable it will not become magically reachable any time, you have a networking problem not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure your android device is in the same network as the page you are trying to reach (probably a local XAMPP server?)?

Wi-Fi enabled and in the same Subnet as the Webserver / Laptop?

Comment: @LikaQ yes, the same. why do you think is that?

Comment: Please try to open the URL in your browser on your Android device and look if you get a different response.

Comment: Also, lookup your local IP on your Android device (Should be at WiFi Settings > Advanced)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your PHP server is configured to receive only requests from localhost interface (loopback 127.0.0.1) instead from all network interfaces.

Comment: but how can i do that?

Comment: @chesca It depends what server do you use ?